# Error while Exporting large data from Reportviewer on azure hosted website

Tags: c#, azure, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, report-viewer2012

I have website hosted on azure. I have used SSRS reportviewer control to showcase my reports. While doing so I faced an issue.

Whenever I export a large amount of data as Excel/PDF/Word/Tiff it abruptly throws the following error :

```
Error: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.ServerUrlRequest(AbortState abortState, String url, Stream outputStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.ServerUrlRequest(AbortState abortState, String url, Stream outputStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.Render(AbortState abortState, String reportPath, String executionId, String historyId, String format, XmlNodeList deviceInfo, NameValueCollection urlAccessParameters, Stream reportStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.InternalRender(Boolean isAbortable, String format, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection urlAccessParameters, Stream reportStream, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection urlAccessParameters, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension)

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerModeSession.RenderReport(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection additionalParams, Boolean cacheSecondaryStreamsForHtml, String& mimeType, String& fileExtension)

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ExportOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response)

   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

It works locally (on a developer machine) or when there is less data. But it didn't work with a large data set when published on azure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Anybody can suggest any pointers to this issue?

Comment: This might be nothing at all but I've just today resolved an issue I had where reports worked great until large and was getting blank data set results back in production. It was down to the load balancer port forward being http/https and not tcp/secure tcp. Might be nothing (especially as your error is unauthorised) but could be worth a shot...